# how to display the image from an http request using angular 2

Tags: angular

I need to display an image from nodejs backend with the help of HTTP get request using angular 2
that's my post image code

```
  <input id="cin" name="cin" type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" 
   placeholder="Upload a file..." multiple/>
```

***component code***

```
onSubmit(){  

this.dataService.postproductcreate(this.model).subscribe(response =>console.log(response),(error) => console.log(error));

    // const fd=new FormData();
    // fd.append('file',this.selectedFile,this.selectedFile.name)
    // this.dataService.uploadimage(fd).subscribe(response =>console.log(response),(error) => console.log(error)

    // );

    const formData: any = new FormData();
    const files: Array<File> = this.filesToUpload;
    console.log(files);

    for(let i =0; i < files.length; i++){
        formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i]['name']);
    }
    console.log('form data variable :   '+ formData.toString());
    this.dataService.uploadimage(formData).subscribe(response =>console.log(response),(error) => console.log(error));
    // window.location.reload();

}
```

***service.ts***

```
uploadimage(data){
   return this._http.post(this.url,data,{withCredentials:true}).map(res=>res.json());  
}
```

Now I want to get the image and display the image in angular 2 from nodejs backend but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Where are you storing the image on backend side?

Comment: Mongodb @Jeto.. and I want to get the image